# Grid-like view in cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm writing an app with a view that has a grid of images (3x3) and it needs to have infinite scroll per row and per column, very similar to the 'Design Museum Collection' app. How would I go about implementing this view? Is there a library that already supports this?  Can this be done in Cocos2d?  Here is a video of the 'Design Museum Collection' app (http://vimeo.com/39260302).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `CCMenuAdvanced` extension is a good place to start.  You can find it here:

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/tree/master/Extensions/CCMenuAdvanced